# How can I capture the value of a React-Bootstrap dropdown list?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I figured out how to use react-bootstrap to display a dropdown list:

```
<DropdownButton bsStyle="success" title="Choose" onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
    <MenuItem key="1">Action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem key="2">Another action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem key="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

But how am I suppose to write the handler for onSelect to capture the option being selected? I tried this but don't know what to write inside:

```
handleSelect: function () {
    // what am I suppose to write in there to get the value?
},
```

Also, is there a way to set an option to be selected by default?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `onSelect` function is passed the selected value

```
<DropdownButton title='Dropdowna' onSelect={function(evt){console.log(evt)}}>
  <MenuItem eventKey='abc'>Dropdown link</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey={['a', 'b']}>Dropdown link</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

In this case if you select the first option, '*abc*' is printed, in the second option you can see an object can be passed in as well.

So in your code

```
handleSelect: function (evt) {
    // what am I suppose to write in there to get the value?
    console.log(evt)
},
```

I'm not sure what you mean by a default value since this isn't a select - the button text is whatever is in the title attribute. If you want to handle a default value you could just set a value when value is `null`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Let me clarify my second question. I have three options in my dropdown list. I want the first option to be selected by default. What is the correct way to accomplish this? Thanks again! Oh, also, where did you find the documentation on `eventKey` ? I did look through react-bootstrap's site and couldn't find it...

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem is these are menu items. The expectation is that something is supposed to happen when the user selects something from the dropdown. It doesn't have the concept of a current value. If you are trying to have a form like element where the user can chose an option and then go on you might want to take a looking <Input>

Comment: I noticed a weird issue. `<DropdownButton bsStyle="primary" title={this.state.value} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>` Then, inside  the `handleSelect`, I wrote `this.setState({value: index});console.log(this.state.value);` When I read the console output, the value seems to be lagging behind. Meaning, when I select an item for the 1st time. The console would output the default value of the state variable. If I select another item, the console would output the value from my previous selection. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: setState is not a synchronous operation in react (From docs)

setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains. 

If you need to do something afterwards, pass a callback as the second parameter of setstate.

Comment: Not to hijack this question, but this did not work for me, I am getting `SyntheticMouseEvent {dispatchConfig: Object, dispatchMarker: ".0.2.0.1.0.0.0.0.1.$=11:0.$=11:0.0", nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: a…}` when trying to log evt

Comment: This doesnt really work. I get the click event not the value inside the dropdown... any idea what I need to do?

Comment: I'm using eventKey.target.innerHTML. Not sure if it is the right approach but it does the job

Comment: The signature of the callback method is not correct here. Reference : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

It should be `handleSelect: function (evtKey, evt) {....` and you can use either the evt or the evtKey to set the title of the Dropdown

Answer (score 4):

you forgot to mention that eventKey is passed as a second parameter, this is the correct form to obtain the value of what you clicked:

```
handleSelect: function (evt,evtKey) {
    // what am I suppose to write in there to get the value?
    console.log(evtKey)
},
```

Comment: Actually, it's the other way round... The function should be `handleSelect: function (evtKey, event) {....`

Reference : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Comment: The correct signature should be `(eventKey: any, event: Object) => any`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the FormControl >> select component for your case:

```
  <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select">
        <option value="select">select</option>
        <option value="other">...</option>
  </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the handleSelect signature as follows (inside the Component Class):

```
handleSelect = (evtKey, evt) => {
    // Get the selectedIndex in the evtKey variable
}
```

To set the default value, you'll need to use the `title` prop on the `DropdownButton`

Ref: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/